Android Application is closed automatically after 12 hours
I have developed an Android application which runs on certain devices (All one model: Samsung Galaxy Active 3 2020, Android 10) and at the end of the day, the devices are connected to charger until tomorrow morning. The devices are rooted and have Android 10.
Now the problem is, after around 12 hours of remaining connected to charger and locked, the application exits without any crash log. I only see this logs from app before it is closed:

04-12 05:53:39.663 30372 30393 I ide.android.myApp: Background
concurrent copying GC freed 151908(5561KB) AllocSpace objects,
8(328KB) LOS objects, 57% free, 4547KB/10MB, paused 837us,82us total
105.335ms
04-12 05:53:39.663 30372 30393 W ide.android.myApp: Reducing the
number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 2937 to 100

What is happening? I also set the "Battery" preference options like the below image in my app settings to "Unrestricted". There is no other Battery-related tools on the device. But the problem still exists.

Might be worth to mention that:
When a device is connected to the charger, In the code, I lock the device:
devicePolicyManager.lockNow();

The application is also pinned (in locktask mode) using below lines but I don't think it is relevant:
val dpm = context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
val adminName = AdminReceiver.getComponentName(context)   
dpm.setLockTaskPackages(adminName, APP_PACKAGES)


https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung

Thanks but wasn't the solution.
